Python 3 multiprocessing.value c_char_p modify doesn't work with bytes()
I have this code, it works:
import time, ctypes
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

def change_var():
    time.sleep(2)
    G_VAR.value, G_VAR_P.value = b'127.0.0.2', 1504
    time.sleep(2)

def main_process():
    while 1:
        p2 = Process(target=print_process)
        p2.start()
        time.sleep(2)

def print_process():
    a = G_VAR.value
    print("HOST ="+a.decode("utf-8")+"PORT = "+str(G_VAR_P.value))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    G_VAR = Value(ctypes.c_char_p, bytes('127.0.0.1', "utf-8"))
    G_VAR_P = Value('i', 1503)

    p = Process(target=change_var)
    p.start()

    p2 = Process(target=main_process)
    p2.start()

But when I replacing G_VAR.value, G_VAR_P.value = b'127.0.0.2', 1504 on
G_VAR.value, G_VAR_P.value = bytes('127.0.0.2',"utf-8"), 1504
variable G_VAR.value becomes null
I expect get 127.0.0.2 in G_VAR when I use bytes()

I found solution. You must use Array for strings instead Value in this situation.
